# Cannot update software because of grub-efi-amd64-signed unmet dependency

Tags: dependencies, update-manager, grub-efi

I am using Ubuntu 20.10. I did a clean install about 2 weeks ago. I have been updating my software regularly without any issues until today.

I ran the Software Updater and got this error:

```
Transaction failed: Package dependencies cannot be resolved
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

grub-efi-amd64-signed:
```

I tried to search for a solution but cannot find one. Does anyone know the issue and work-around?

Thanks!

[image: Software Updater window]

[image: Error message in Software Updater]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the same error with the Software Updater on Ubuntu Budgie 20.10 this morning.
I manually updated though command line and when I got back to the updater it says that everything is up to date.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```